# Why can't the data be fitted?

Tags: fitting, special-functions, nonlinear

```
In[23]:= sj = {{43.68, 1.}，{206.42, 0.76}，{398.11, 0.58}，{1019.47, 
     0.42}，{1910.44, 0.33}，{2964.39, 0.26}，{4116.84, 0.22}，{5318.17, 
     0.19}，{6505.90, 0.16}，{7709.48, 0.15}，{8827.55, 0.13}，{9984.18, 
     0.12}，{11015.08, 0.11}};
model = \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 0\), \(2\)]\(
\*FractionBox[\(4\), \(\((2*\ k + 1)\)*\ \[Pi]\)]*1 (*c0*) *
    MittagLefflerE[\[Beta], \((\((\(-d\))\)*\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\((2\ *k + 1)\), \(2\)]\ *
\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(2\)]\ *
\*SuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(\[Beta]\)])\)]\ *
    Sin[\((2\ *k + 1)\)*\ \[Pi]*\ 0.5]\)\);
FindFit[sj, model, {\[Beta], d}, t]
```

During evaluation of In[23]:= FindFit::nrlnum: The function value {-2.73453*10^-8 (，^12)+0.254648 MittagLefflerE[1.,-5.45154*10^45 (，^12)^1.]-0.424413 MittagLefflerE[1.,-1.96256*10^45 (，^12)^1.]+1.27324 MittagLefflerE[1.,-2.18062*10^44 (，^12)^1.]} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {1} at {[Beta],d} = {1.,1.}.

```
Out[25]= FindFit[{{2.20943*10^43 (，^12), 2.73453*10^-8 (，^12)}}, 
 0.254648 MittagLefflerE[\[Beta], -25 d \[Pi]^2 t^\[Beta]] - 
  0.424413 MittagLefflerE[\[Beta], -9 d \[Pi]^2 t^\[Beta]] + 
  1.27324 MittagLefflerE[\[Beta], -d \[Pi]^2 t^\[Beta]], {\[Beta], d},
  t]
```

[image]
As you can see, just two parameters 'beta and d' in the fitted function 'model', which is used to fit a series of data points.
I can't understand the warnings comprehensively and unable to fix the problem. Is there any problem in the data or the fitted function?
Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: Your `sj={...}` definition is riddled with non standard comma characters. Replacing them by the normal ","-character fixes this issue. Your fit has problems converging though. I think you have to provide good starting values.

Comment: Look at `{43.68，1} // FullForm` what shows: `List[Times[43.68, \:ff0c]]`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the additional confounding introduced by the comma-like character is not useful for future visitors. Fixing that makes all the errors reported in the post as irrelevant. The OP can revise the post providing details about $\beta,d,t$ and by focusing on the fitting part. It would also be helpful to stay responsive to the comments.

Comment: I have revised the comma problem, and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure **model** is correct ?

Comment: frankly, I'm not sure. but changing the model is the last choice, after all the math trials.

Comment: You have not "revised the comma problem".  `sj` in your question still has bad syntax, and running your codes still produces error messages.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version 
(*"13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"*)
ClearAll["`*"]; Remove["`*"];

data = {{43.68, 1.}, {206.42, 0.76}, {398.11, 0.58}, {1019.47, 
0.42}, {1910.44, 0.33}, {2964.39, 0.26}, {4116.84, 
0.22}, {5318.17, 0.19}, {6505.9, 0.16}, {7709.48, 
0.15}, {8827.55, 0.13}, {9984.18, 0.12}, {11015.08, 0.11}};

model = Sum[4/((2* k + 1)* Pi)*1(*c0*)*
MittagLefflerE[β, ((-d)* (2 *k + 1)^2 *π^2 *t^β)]*
Sin[(2 *k + 1)* Pi* 1/2], {k, 0, 2}];

M = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {{β, 0.7}, { d, 0.0002}}, t]

(*Good starting values solves the problem: β=0.7 and d= 0.0002} *)

(*Visualize the data and Model:*)

Show[{ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black], 
Plot[M // Normal, {t, data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, 
PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image: Data and fit]

```
{fr, sr1, sr2} = M[{"FitResiduals", "StandardizedResiduals", 
"StudentizedResiduals"}];

(*Visualize the residuals:*)

Map[ListPlot[#, Filling -> 0] &, {fr, sr1, sr2}]
```

[image: Residual plots]

Comment: Thanks! The key point is to find the initial value of 'beta' and 'd '. I have to ask another question to find the general solution to get good starting value.

Comment: @Stan "good starting values"  I found with trial and error.